# Unable to find deploy to server button in mavensmate

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I have downloaded mavens mate with sublime to work on salesforce project but im unable to find deploy to server code after validating code for deployment could anyone help me out what's actually problem or steps should i follow to get a deployment to server button

System information 
Windows 7 ultimate 64 bit 
sublime 3 
mavensmate -0.0.11

Answer (score 1):

Deploy to Server is one of the top-level menu options in MavensMate after you open your project.

[image]

This is on the latest stable release of MavensMate Desktop, 0.0.10. I've not tested 0.0.11, which was never released from beta.